# ParallelSubmit not working as expected

Tags: parallelization

I have the following code where `ParallelSubmit` called on `OverBar` does not return the same result as non-parallel code even though I used `DistributeDefinitions`. Without the `OverBar` it works fine. The code

```
A = Sum[lambda[order] (r - rp)^order, {order, 0, 2}];
OverBar[x_ + y_] := OverBar[x] + OverBar[y];
OverBar[x_ y_] := OverBar[x] OverBar[y];
OverBar[x_ /; NumericQ[x]] := Conjugate[x]
OverBar[x_[xa__]] := OverBar[x][xa]
OverBar[x_ /; MemberQ[RealSymbols, x]] := x
DefaultRealSymbols = {Power, r, rp};
RealSymbols = DefaultRealSymbols;
DistributeDefinitions[A, OverBar];

Coefficient[A, r - rp, 2]
WaitAll[ParallelSubmit[Coefficient[A, r - rp, 2]]]
Coefficient[OverBar[A], r - rp, 2]
WaitAll[ParallelSubmit[Coefficient[OverBar[A], r - rp, 2]]]
```

returns

```
lambda[2]
lambda[2]
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(lambda\), \(_\)]\)[2]
0
```

where the 0 should be `\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(lambda\), \(_\)]\)[2]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that evaluating the command using `ParallelEvaluate` works as expected?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. When I run your code with `OverBar` replaced with `overbar`, it works. The same applies when I use `ParallelEvaluate` instead of `WaitAll`. So it looks like a bug to me. At least, it is unexpected behaviour, as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `DistributeDefinitions` does not work for any of the built-in operators without built-in meaning. You can check by running

```
ParallelEvaluate@DownValues@OverBar
```

that none of the custom `DownValues` have been distributed to the parallel kernels.

As a work around you could wrap your definitions for `OverBar` in a `ParallelEvaluate` to evaluate the definitions on the parallel kernels. Alternatively, you can put your definitions in a package, and load it using `ParallelNeeds`. This has the advantage that the definitions will reload on any newly (re)started kernel.

Finally, you could change you definitions to not use the built-in `OverBar` operator but say `overbar`. You can then get Mathematica to put the Over bar in the output using

```
Format[overbar[x_]] := OverBar[x]
```

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up on mmeent's answer, you can distribute the definitions for `OverBar` via (see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258819/73380))

```
Block[
  {Parallel`Protected`$ExcludedContexts=
     DeleteCases[Parallel`Protected`$ExcludedContexts,"System`*"]},
  DistributeDefinitions[OverBar];
];
```

which leads to your expected result

```
lambda[2]
lambda[2]
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(lambda\), \(_\)]\)[2]
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(lambda\), \(_\)]\)[2]
```