# Why are DownValues of symbols in System` such as CircleDot not distributed to subkernels?

Tags: parallelization

Consider a symbol in `System` such as `CircleDot`. I want to redefine this symbol and distribute the definition to subkernel, to use with `ParallelEvaluate` or the likes.

With a standard symbol in `Global` I can simply do

```
foo[___] := 1;
Print @ DownValues @ foo
ParallelEvaluate[Print @ DownValues @ foo];
```

which will show that the definition is automatically distributed to subkernels.

However, doing the same with `CircleDot` doesn't work:

[image]

Using `DistributeDefinitions@CircleDot` doesn't seem to change this. Why does this happen?

I know I can force subkernels to accept the definition by directly doing something like `ParallelEvaluate[CircleDot[___]:=1]`, but this might not be desirable in some cases, and also I would like to understand why some symbols seem to behave different in this context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are function definitions distributed to parallel kernels?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128503/how-are-function-definitions-distributed-to-parallel-kernels)

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128287/12

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, hadn't seen those. So a possible solution is changing `$DistributedContexts`. This is however in this case not desirable, as far as I can tell, as we don't want to let the whole of ``System` `` distribute. Is there a way to have `DistributeDefinitions` work on a specific function in ``System` ``? The solution given in the linked post, ``DistributeDefinitions[const`precisionRate]``, doesn't seem to work in this case: ``DistributeDefinitions[System`CircleDot]`` doesn't do what it should

Comment: I was going to say that the solution is not to change `$DistributedContexts` globally, but to change the `DistributedContexts` option of value in a single `DistributeDefinitions` call when distributing `CircleDot`. However, I just tried this and it does not work. It seems there is a hard limitation on System symbols. I am not surprised, as distributing the wrong ones could cause trouble, and `DistributeDefinitions` does indeed distribute dependent symbols recursively.

Comment: Thus what I'd do is just to re-issue the definition on the subkernels with `ParallelEvaluate`: `ParallelEvaluate[CircleDot[___]:=1]`. A better solution is to put the `CircleDot` definition into a package (eventually you'll end up doing this anyway) and load that package using `ParallelNeeds`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I retracted the close vote, and I'm going to sleep on this. I'm just too tired tonight.

Comment: In trying to find an automatic way to identify the symbols that need to be redefined in each parallel kernel, I find it weird that `Language\`ExtendedFullDefinition[System\`CircleDot]`is an empty definition list, even after being defined. In contrast, `Definition[CircleDot]` and `Information[CircleDot, "Definitions"]` shows the user definition. Thought i'd mention it.

Comment: @thorimur to see the definition list you have to use ```Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[CircleDot, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]``` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some [spelunking](https://github.com/szhorvat/Spelunking) of `DistributeDefinitions` shows that all contexts listed in `` Parallel`Protected`$ExcludedContexts `` are by default excluded from being distributed. In particular, `` Parallel`Protected`DistDefs `` has the line

```
updates = ExtendedFullDefinition[expr, "ExcludedContexts"->$ExcludedContexts]
```

So to make sure that new definitions of symbols in `` System` `` are also distributed you can use something like

```
CircleDot[___]:=1;

Block[
  {Parallel`Protected`$ExcludedContexts=
    DeleteCases[Parallel`Protected`$ExcludedContexts,"System`*"]},
  DistributeDefinitions[CircleDot];
];

ParallelEvaluate[Print @ DownValues @ CircleDot];
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[CircleDot[___]]:>1}
> {HoldPattern[CircleDot[___]]:>1}
> {HoldPattern[CircleDot[___]]:>1}
> {HoldPattern[CircleDot[___]]:>1}
> ```

This way we also only distribute new definitions for `CircleDot` and nothing else in `` System` ``.

Regarding the comment of @thorimur: you do not get the full definition of `CircleDot` from
`` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``, as the default option `"ExcludedContexts"->Automatic` seems to filter `` System` `` as well.
So by setting this option yourself you can also see the full definition

```
Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[CircleDot, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]

Language`DefinitionList[HoldForm[CircleDot] -> {OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {HoldPattern[CircleDot[___]] :> 1}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, 
Attributes -> {}}, HoldForm[BlankNullSequence] -> {OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, 
NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {Protected}}, HoldForm[Rule] -> {OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, 
DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {HoldPattern[Rule::rhs] -> "Pattern `1` appears on the right-hand side of rule `2`."}, 
Attributes -> {Protected, SequenceHold}}, HoldForm[List] -> {OwnValues -> {}, SubValues -> {}, UpValues -> {}, DownValues -> {}, 
NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {Locked, Protected}}]
```